# Optimize query using Concat method

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have a query which uses join, then *group by* `caseId` and then a concat-like function using `STUFF`.

```
SELECT distinct [CaseID], STUFF((SELECT ';' +space(1)+ A.[AssignedPathologist]+' ' FROM CTE1 A  
WHERE A.[CaseID]=B.[CaseID] FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') As [AssignedPathologist]  
From CTE1 B   
Group By [CaseID]
```

The problem is that this query is super, super-slow and I tried to optimize it using `CONCAT` instead.

```
SELECT distinct A.[CaseID], [AssignedPathologist] = CASE A.AssignedPathologist = B.AssignedPathologist
WHEN 1 THEN A.AssignedPathologist
ELSE CONCAT(A.AssignedPathologist, ' ', B.AssignedPathologist)
END
FROM CTE1 A
INNER JOIN CTE1 B ON A.[CaseID]=B.[CaseID] 
END
```

but it gives me syntax error here

```
[AssignedPathologist] = CASE A.AssignedPathologist = B.AssignedPathologist
```

which is logic because I used twice `=` here.

Is there any method to optimize my query using CONCAT or another methods ?

Thank you

Comment: That clearly isn't the whole query there. You reference `CTE1` and `CTE2` in the SQL, yet don't include those expressions. Also `DISTINCT` can be very costly. Giving us the full query, the DDL of the involved objects (inlcuding their indexes), and the query plan (search Paste the Plan) will greatly help us help you here.

Comment: Also a `GROUP BY` with no aggregation, and a `DISTINCT` makes little sense. If your `GROUP BY` is correct, you will already have distinct results, so making the instance scan the entire dataset (again) for duplicates is only going to slow the query down.

Comment: @Larnu, I don't have CTE2. Also, I forgot to mention that creating CTE1 and CTE2 it is optimized well.

Comment: So, what i attached is the query which takes a lot of time.

Comment: That query, on it's own, isn't what's taking a long time. The CTE could easily be having an impact; especially as it's being run twice. Post the full query, along with the execution plan and DDL... Help us help you.

Comment: A note you your `CASE` expression (`CASE A.AssignedPathologist = B.AssignedPathologist`) . The syntax for  `CASE` is either `CASE {expression} WHEN {expression} THEN ...` or `CASE WHEN {Boolean Expression} THEN...`. You have `CASE {Boolean Expression}` which is not valid T-SQL. See [CASE (Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for examples on how to write a `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try with this :

```
SELECT [CaseID], 
       STUFF( (SELECT CONCAT('; ', A.[AssignedPathologist])
               FROM CTE1 A  
               WHERE A.[CaseID] = B.[CaseID] 
               FOR XML PATH('') 
               ),1, 1, ''
            ) As [AssignedPathologist]  
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CaseID CTE1 B) B;
```

For newer versions you can use `string_agg()` :

```
SELECT CASEID, STRING_AGG(AssignedPathologist, '; ') AS AssignedPathologist
FROM CTE1 C1
GROUP BY CASEID;
```

Comment: I have the same execution time using this. Anyway, +1 for your effort.

Comment: Tag the database version that you are using.

Comment: SQL Server 2017

Comment: Yes, your second solution seems to works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Is `STRING_AGG` a fastest alternative for what i am looking for ?